# Setting up extra IP addresses

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ip

I have a dedicated server from OVH, recently bought 4 extra IP addresses (/30) and I'm very unsure about how to add them to my dedicated server, so I can use them.

For example, my server's original assigned public IP address is: `99.99.99.99`
And the IP addresses that I have purchased are:

```
(100.100.100.101/30)
100.100.100.101
100.100.100.102
100.100.100.103
100.100.100.104
```

How would I do that? My purpose is to setup an OpenVPN server and assign 4 IP addresses for myself, when I connect to it.

My server is running with Ubuntu 14.04 LTS (if it changes anything)

Comment: Did you try search query like "How to add IP address to Ubuntu?" It would have yielded results like http://askubuntu.com/questions/313877/how-do-i-add-an-additional-ip-address-to-etc-network-interfaces with detailed info. Let us know where exactly you go wrong after demonstrating having tried at least something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to edit your /etc/network/interfaces to add a new ip address to your interface like so

```
  auto eth0
  iface eth0 inet static
          address 192.168.0.42
          network 192.168.0.0
          netmask 255.255.255.0
          broadcast 192.168.0.255
          gateway 192.168.0.1
```

That said if you dont know where to be adding new ips to a dedicated server you really shouldnt be messing around with this stuff as you could end up losing access to your server